How to find and remove unknown odor from home
Since June 2024 I have an exhaust type odor in my house.
I have hired 5 HVAC companies, and they cannot find the problem. I replaced the evaporator coil, UV light bulb in air handler, turned UV lights off for several weeks, replaced P-Trap condensation line, professionally cleaned air ducts, replaced loose insulation around supply and return ducts, had negative pressure place in house, ozone, chlorine dioxide gas, air quality test done and everything noted on report removed.
Odor is not present all the time. It doesn't matter if Heat Pump AC and now heat is on or off. Home inspector who sampled air said it smelled like wet insulation. Termite inspector said same thing. HVAC companies did not find any wet insulation. One HVAC described it as moth balls. Others could not describe it.
I removed my 5" media filter and used different types of 1" filter at the return vent, claimed, odor absorbing filters with no success. I do not smell the odor outside the house.
I no longer call HVAC companies, but I called a restoration company and home inspectors who do not look for just odors.
My home is on a slab with attached garage. No odor in the attic.

There are many similar questions already on this site. Did you search? Please don't YELL AT US. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Ultimately this comes down to "Keep looking". Example: if wet insulation could cause the smell, the only way to truly confirm no insulation is wet is to look in all the places where insulation exists and see if it is wet. That technically means opening all the walls, because any roof leak could let water into the insulation. It might not be water: it could be animals using the home for a den, with the resulting musk and urine/feces.

When the odor is present, is it everywhere in the house or more localized? Does the HVAC running effect it at all?

Do you have carpet on some floors?  I purchased a home with bad odors that would actually come and go.   I had planned on removing the carpet but did other renovations and put up with the smell.  It wasn't improved with paint, or new cabinets or replacing bathrooms, but when I pulled up the carpet and threw it in the dumpster the smell was gone.

If you reach the end of your rope and it's either get rid of the odor or move somewhere else, you can have a lab identify the specific compounds in the air that are causing the odor. They won't identify what is causing it, but what it is. Come back here and post the results and someone may identify where it comes from. (E.g., you say "formic acid" and someone here will say "you have ants.") Example lab (no affiliation): https://lcslaboratory.com/odor-testing/

(continued) The lab gives you a sealed container with activated charcoal in it. You open the container and leave it exposed to the air in the house for a time. The lab heats the charcoal to drive off the odor-causing chemical and puts it through a gas chromatograph + mass spectrometer. A computer looks at the humps and bumps in the output of these two machines and figures out what chemical(s) were absorbed by the charcoal.
